# Slow WIFI speeds on Win 7 (not in Ubuntu)

Tags: wireless-networking

I have run speedtest on my WIFI connection on a dual-boot computer ni Ubuntu and in Win 7. In Windows, the download speed is about 3M/second. In Ubuntu, it is around 10M/second. I can't figure out why there'd be this difference. My wifi card is b/g/n. Any ideas about how to debug this?

EDIT 10/3

So I ran a virus scanner called Housecall, which I have known to work well in the past, and it removed some program called BitGuard. But the downloads speeds have remained the same. I also downloaded the softwar for what the wifi device listed in my device manager, which is a realtek rtl8191se wireless lan 802.11n pci-e, but still no improvement. I've also looked with Net Meter to see if there is something drawing data when I'm not, and there was nothing. So I'm still at a loss as to what is going on here. My motherboard in cidentially is the asrock z77e-itx

Comment: Which card is that? Might it be a broadcom card? If in doubt, lspci -vnn | grep -i net in linux tells us the make and Vendor and Product codes.

Comment: Run any network-monitor to check if there are some programs/viruses that are using your connection. Is it happenning when you are connected to internet using a LAN port?

Comment: Make sure your drivers are up to date.  Windows this can be a bit tricky because depending on your wireless vendor, this could be through Windows Update, the vendor itself or another source (the computer OEM for example).

Comment: Thanks for these tips. I'm gonna try some of them out this coming week/weekend, and will report back.